# TypeErr: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm executing a javascript function but it's not executing properly.

```
<html>
<style>
.gear
{
position: relative; display: block; margin-bottom: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; float: left;
}
label {float: left; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; color: #696969; font-size: 12px; width: 100px; }
.datainfo { float: left; margin-left: 10px; font-size: 11px; color: #333; }
.savebtn { margin-left: 2em; background: #5972a8; float:left; color:#CCCCCC; padding:5px; border-radius: 3px; display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit_info()
{
try
{
    document.getElementbyId("txt").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("svbtn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementbyId("pemail").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("edit").style.display = "none";
}
catch(err)
{
    alert(err);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gear">
                <label>Primary E-Mail:</label>
                <span id="pemail" class="datainfo">Some text to edit</span>
                <span id="pemail" class="datainfo"><input type="text" value="" id="txt" style="display:none;" /></span>
                <a href="#" style = "margin-left: 2em;" id="edit" onclick="edit_info();">Edit Info</a>
                <a class="savebtn" id="svbtn">Save</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After executing the code I'm getting the Error "TypeErr: undefined is not a function" Please suggest the solution in purely javascript.

Comment: You have duplicate `id` attributes in your markup. `id` attributes must be unique within a document.

Comment: There is no `getElementbyId`, only `getElementById` - javascript is case-sensitive. Also `onclick="edit_info(); return false;"`

Comment: after making id unique (ids have been changed), it's still generating the same error @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested earlier it's

```
document.getElementById("id_of_element");
```

Here's the working [***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/jckqz5v3/)

You can have a detail documentation of *document.getElementById* from [***here***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Another thing is you shouldn't have more than one element having same *id*. As *id* is for individual element only. For that you should use *class*.

Take a look about *id* from [***here***](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)
and *class* from [***here***](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
document.getElementById("id").whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

in two of four you mentioned `getElementById("")` but in rest you mention `getElementbyId("")`,which is not a function because javascrit is a case sensitive.

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0cfWAN76VgudTyXQiF6q?p=preview)